# Is there a shared hosting provider (not Hostinger) that will allow setting CORS headers in the "/.well-known" directory?

Tags: stellar.toml, server

Hostinger just confirmed that making changes to the /.well-known folder with .htaccess is not possible on their shared hosting plan, so I can't set the CORS header on the stellar.toml file. So it looks like I need to find a new web host. Here is the official response I received:

*"The .well-known directory is server-default, so that is why overriding and making changes to it is not possible on a shared hosting plan, as important data/information is stored there. To make meaningful changes in this directory, you would need root access, which is only available on our VPS plans."*

Has anyone had success with another shared hosting provider?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Namecheap Hosting or Hawkhost, those support CORS on shared hosting.

Comment: That is two answers.  Please post them separately so that they may be voted upon and accepted separately.  Also, please give some additional information about these services.